# Sending email after successful mysqldump

Tags: shell, scripting

I've a script which will take backup of mysql db through mysqldump. I'd like add another option in this script to send an automatic email if the dump is successful or failure.

Here's the script:

```
#!/bin/sh
BACKUP=/data/backup/sql2/new_backup/daily
cd $BACKUP
mkdir `date '+%d-%m-%Y'`
NOW=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")

MUSER="root"
MPASS="mypass"
MHOST="sql4"
MYSQL="$(which mysql)"
MYSQLDUMP="$(which mysqldump)"
GZIP="$(which gzip)"

DBS="$($MYSQL -u $MUSER -h $MHOST -p$MPASS -Bse 'show databases')"
for db in $DBS
do
 FILE=$BACKUP/$NOW/mysql-$db.$NOW-$(date +"%T").sql.gz
 $MYSQLDUMP -u $MUSER -h $MHOST -p$MPASS --lock-all-tables $db | $GZIP -9 > $FILE
done
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mysqldump` will finish with exit code `0` if all went well. You can use that:

```
#!/bin/sh
BACKUP=/data/backup/sql2/new_backup/daily
cd $BACKUP
mkdir `date '+%d-%m-%Y'`
NOW=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y")

MUSER="root"
MPASS="mypass"
MHOST="sql4"
MYSQL="$(which mysql)"
MYSQLDUMP="$(which mysqldump)"
GZIP="$(which gzip)"
MAIL="youradress@example.com"
MAILER="$(which mail)"
STATUSFILE="/tmp/statusfile.$NOW"


echo "Backup report from $NOW" > $STATUSFILE
DBS="$($MYSQL -u $MUSER -h $MHOST -p$MPASS -Bse 'show databases')"
for db in $DBS
do
 FILE=$BACKUP/$NOW/mysql-$db.$NOW-$(date +"%T").sql.gz
 $MYSQLDUMP -u $MUSER -h $MHOST -p$MPASS --lock-all-tables $db | $GZIP -9 > $FILE
 if [ "$?" -eq "0" ] then; 
   echo "$db backup is OK" >> $STATUSFILE
  else 
   echo "##### WARNING: #####  $db backup failed" >> $STATUSFILE
  fi
done
$MAILER -s "Backup report for $NOW" -- $MAIL < $STATUSFILE
rm $STATUSFILE
```

I haven't tested this, but this is the general way to do it.

Comment: It should work, but I'd suggest use `mail` command, as mutt might be not installed, and mail is more common. Use something like `cat $FILE | mail -s "subject" to@address1 to@addres2`

Comment: In the first version I assumed that the dump file should be send by mail, and mail(x) can't send MIME attachments, AFAIK. In the second version, I use mail instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash 

TO="email@example.org" 
SUBJECT="testmail"      
MSG="bla bla bla"

/usr/sbin/sendmail -t <<EOF
to:$TO
subject:$SUBJECT
$MSG
EOF
```

You can also add the "from" field, if necessary.